# pubnub - publish fallback to push notifications doesn't work

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, real-time, pubnub

I am using android with pubnub.

I did the subscribe/publish tutorial and it works, I have a working chat (when app is open).

After reading all of the tutorials, I understood that while the app is in the background or closed, the `publish` method should fallback to send a push notification to everyone who `subscribe` and `enablePushNotificationsOnChannel` to the channel.

For some reason it doesn't work for me, and I am not sure how should it work.

From the tutorial, **There should be one piece of code that either:**

1. sends the data throught the realtime channels.
2. sends a push notification if app is closed/in background.

**From the website:**

```
/ Send Push Notification to all devices
// registered to `my_channel`

JSONObject jso = null;
try {
jso = new JSONObject("{
'aps' : {
'alert' : 'You got your emails.'," + "
'badge' : 9,
'sound' : 'bingbong.aiff'}," + "
'acme 1': 42
}");
pubnub.publish("my_channel", jso,
new Callback(){
@Override
public void successCallback(String arg0,
Object arg1) {
System.out.println(arg1);
}
```

**And also:**

```
Sending Notifications
Sending a notification requires creating a JSON object. It is then added to a PubNub GCM specific message (the message is formatted for you).

public void sendNotification() {
    PnGcmMessage gcmMessage = new PnGcmMessage();
    JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jso.put("GCMSays", "hi");
    } catch (JSONException e) { }
    gcmMessage.setData(jso);

    PnMessage message = new PnMessage(
            pubnub,
            "your channel name",
            callback,
            gcmMessage);
    try {
        message.publish();
    } catch (PubnubException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Note that we have to create the callback methods which will be fired when the message is published:

public static Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Success on Channel " + CHANNEL + " : " + message);
    }
    @Override
    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Error On Channel " + CHANNEL + " : " + error);
    }
};
```

So, obviously, these are two different pieces of code, and none of them covered both options (real-time channel when app is open, push notification when app is closed).

I need the piece of code that:

1. if the app is opened - sends the data through the channels.
2. if the app is closed/in background - sends push notification.

Answer (score 3):

## PubNub Mobile Push Notifications

The publisher does not know or care whether subscribers are active (foreground) or inactive (background or not running at all - *kill state*) on the device. Publisher always publishes the message with a GCM (and possibly APNS) payload.

- Active apps will receive both and will prevent the display of the push notification via the OS's push msg receiver listener.
- Inactive apps will receive only the push notification and display that. When end user taps the push msg, it will open the app where you can get the missed message and display the full content in your app's UI.

See my article, [Sending APNS and GCM Messages to Subscribers and Mobile Push Notification Services in One API Call](https://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/498/sending-apns-and-gcm-messages-to-subscribers-and-mobile-push-notification-services-in-one-api-call), as a primer on how PubNub push notifications work.

From there, you might have further questions but this should give you a good start on how to use PubNub mobile push notifications.